# Getting Second Span using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a site that has the following div:

```
<div class="sr-2">
    <span>Test</span>
    <span>Outcome 2234</span>
</div>
```

How can I **scrape** the data from the second span? I have been playing around with the code below but not getting anywhere:

```
test_outcomes = container.find('div', class_='sr-2').text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) and then slicing to get the second one.

```
container.find('div', class_='sr-2').find_all("span")[1].text
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use following example how to extract the text from second `<span>`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="sr-2">
    <span>Test</span>
    <span>Outcome 2234</span>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one("div.sr-2 > span:nth-of-type(2)").text)   # or:
print(soup.select("div.sr-2 > span")[1].text)                   # or: 
print(soup.find("div", class_="sr-2").find_all("span")[1].text)
```

Prints:

```
Outcome 2234
Outcome 2234
Outcome 2234
```

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would give Andrej a run for his money and add a few more options:

```
print(soup.select_one("div.sr-2 > span + span").text)   # or:
print(soup.select_one("div.sr-2 > span ~ span").text)   # or:
print(soup.select_one("div.sr-2 > span:nth-child(even)").text)   # or:
print(soup.select_one("div.sr-2 > span:nth-child(n+2)").text)   # or:
print(soup.select_one("div.sr-2 > span:last-child").text)   # or:
print(soup.select_one("div.sr-2 > span:last-of-type").text)   # or:
print(soup.select_one("div.sr-2 > span:nth-last-child(1)").text)   # or:
print(soup.select_one("div.sr-2 > span").find_next('span').text) # or:
print(soup.select_one("div.sr-2 > span").find_next_sibling("span").text)
```

And there are yet more....... That is one very skinned cat (or [well shaken carbuncle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/euphemism-for-theres-more-than-one-way-to-skin-a-cat/91916)!).

Now, of course, the importance is to understand the differences between these and when, in reality, to use them. I would suggest reading the following:

1. [bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
2. [soupsieve documentation](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/)
3. [MDN Web Docs - CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
4. [whatwg.org selectors](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selectors)